# specific constraint, instead of a general constraint for a least square problem

Tags: optimization, constraints, least-squares, constraint-programming, cvxpy

Let's say that I have a simple problem like this at hand.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 143, -144, -343, 56]
,[-7632,  77, -277, 63 ]
,[ 55, -75,   74, 744 ]
,[-22 , 177, -28, 12]
,[-848 , -433 , 121, 54]
,[98, 75, 155, 87]])

b = [-114, -734, -270,  577,  676, 122]

n = 4
x = cp.Variable(n)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A*x - b))
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
result = prob.solve()

print(" x =", x.value)
```

The answer of this problem is `x = [ 0.04802172 -0.7942824   0.88297924 -0.47109203]` where:

```
 x1 = 0.04802172, x2 = -0.7942824, x3 = 0.88297924, x4 = -0.47109203
```

I know that I can define a general constriant for this problem, something like this that can be applied on all the resluts :

```
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
```

But I was wondering if I can apply the below constraints to the problem which is more specific:

```
1) abs(x2)< abs(x1) (and so on and so forth forth ,ie, abs(x4)< abs(x3) , ...)
2) The last two results (in this case x3 and x4) are free to obtain any values.
```

In other words, I need the second value of each pair of answers to be smaller than the first value, except for the last two answers.

I appreciate any help regarding this problem-defining issue that I have. 
Thanks

Comment: And what did your try? What about `constraints = [cp.abs(i) <= cp.abs(i-1) for i in range(n-1, 0)]`? Of course the overall model would look questionable then, but well... not sure what you target. Remark: there is no strict equality in convex-opt and if needed, it's only possible with helper-epsilons.

Comment: @sascha, It doesn't work. I was thinking to try quadratic programing, not sure yet. I need for each pair of answers the second value be smaller than the first value.

Comment: You can index into a vector using standard indexing suntex. For example, if x is a variable (and not a scalar), you can write x[0] >= 0 to constrain the first component to be nonnegative.

Comment: Are your variables still non-negative? If they are, you don't need the abs and those constraints will be linear and easy. Just add `[x[1] >= x[0]]` to `constraints`

Comment: Cvxpy has a function `abs()`. However, absolute values also often create problems with convexity. You can always linearize yourself (when needed with the aid of extra binary variables). I.e. `abs(x) <= 3.14` (or `abs(x[2]) <= 3.14`) is ok, but `abs(x) >= 3.14` needs work.